# Line break of table notes after first column in a long table

Tags: line-breaking, landscape, tablenotes, xltabular

I am creating a long table using `xltabular` in landscape format using `landscape`. I add table notes using the `tablenotes` environment:

```
 \begin{landscape}
        \begin{xltabular}[l]{X X X X}
            \caption{Table 1}
            \label{Table 1}     
            Column 1  & Column 2  & Column 3 & Column 4
%here are a lot of rows over multiple pages

               \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\scriptsize
                 \item This text breaks after the first column. I want the text to expand the whole page width.
               \end{tablenotes} 
        \end{xltabular}
 \end{landscape}
```

However, the text breaks after the first column. I want the text to expand over all for columns (something like \linewidth) over the whole page width.

Do you know how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without more context, it’s hard to say exactly what you should do. We would need the package that you’re getting `tablenotes` from, for example. The `threeparttable` package, for example, expects the `tablenotes` to come after the `tabular` (or equivalent) command has finished. If you really want the `tablenotes` Inside the `xltabular` you should wrap it in `\multicolumn{4}{X}{...}` so it spans all four columns and isn’t just in the first column.

Comment: you'd need to give tabularx a bit of help `\multicolumn{4}{X}` would span 4 columns but in a parbox as wide as other X columns

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would construct a MWE from the code fragment you provided so far:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{ThreePartTable}
      \begin{TableNotes}[flushleft]\scriptsize
        \item This text breaks after the first column. I want the text to expand the whole page width.
      \end{TableNotes}
      \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{X X X X}
            \caption{Table 1}
            \label{Table 1}\\
          \endhead
            \insertTableNotes 
          \endfoot
          Column 1  & Column 2  & Column 3 & Column 4
        \end{xltabular}
    \end{ThreePartTable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For long tables breaking over pages, you have to load the `threeparttablex`, which has a slightly different syntax: you *declare* a `TableNotes` environment before entering the xltabular environment, and *insert* the  notes with the command `\insertTableNotes` in the `lastfoot` section of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{xltabular, threeparttablex, makecell}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{ThreePartTable}%
\setTableNoteFont{\footnotesize}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{TableNotes}[flushleft]
  \item[]\lipsum[11]
\end{TableNotes}
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{X X X X}
        \caption{Table 1} \label{Table 1}\\
\toprule
        Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4 \\
    \endhead
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes \\
\endlastfoot
Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text & Some other text some other text some other text some other text some other text & & \\
    \end{xltabular}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]